# Is there an easy way to find files by extension type to put them into a File array in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I've searched and searched, and I'm looking for a library or method that will allow me to find files in the current directory by extension, (.zip for example).  I want to load these into a File array.  I know I can get all the files in a directory with listfiles() then do some logic to get just the zip files, but I was wondering if I'm just doing too much work to accomplish this. I do not want to use any third party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29).

Since `FilenameFilter` is a single method interface, you can implement it using a lambda expression in Java 8.

```
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".zip"));
```

Or with an anonymous class in any Java version:

```
File[] files = new File(".").listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".zip");
    }
});
```

**Update**

Since file extensions are normally not case-sensitive, you might want to use:

```
name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")
```

Comment: looks great, one question... I'm testing this on a Windows box, however this app will run from a unix box.  Will the "." still work or will I need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

File provides a overloaded 'listFiles' method where you can pass an FileNameFilter.

You can instantiate the 'FileNameFilter' as an anonymous class.
The following will return all Files which ends with .txt

```
File f = new File("/path/to/directory");
String ext = ".txt";

File[] arr = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(ext);
    }
});
```